# can access url with android device browser but NOT within android application

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

It seems it is strange problem. i have url which is working from browser, but same url i am trying to use to post the data though android application resulting in "java.net.UnknownHostException ". I am able to connect and post to the url from virtual device. I have everything suggested in this site but without any results ant help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: Some time if you increase the socket connection timeout time for your http client request , it will resolve the issue .

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to gave your App Internet permission. Just add this in your Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```